# ampscript HTTPPost2 equivalent in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I have a working ampscript to create a subscriber_key

```
 SET @url = Concat("https://xxxxx/sk_generator?email=", @email_address)

        /* Call SK API */
        SET @output = HTTPPost2(@url, "text/html", "", true, @generated_sk, @response_header, "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, sdch, br")
        SET @clean_sk = Trim(@generated_sk)
```

what would be the equivalent in SSJS?

```
   var contentType = "text/html";
    var url = "https://xxxxx/sk_generator?email=test@test.com";
    var headerNames = "Accept-Encoding";
    var headerValues = "gzip, deflate, sdch, br";
    var responseContent = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, headerNames, headerValues)
    
Write("result " + Stringify(responseContent));
```

This is showing rubbish data. Not a showstopper as I can do it with ampscript but I was wondering why I cannot achieve the same.

Comment: Any way you can share what the difference you are receiving between AMPscript and SSJS (e.g. define rubbish data) to help debug what the issue could be? For example, HTTP.Post has 5 properties (despite the documentation only showing 4) so in your example, `headerNames` is actually filling in the 'payload' section and not the header names part.  Would need to be `HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headverValues)` and I would also put the header values into an array instead of as Strings, just for syntax matching. `payload` can be null if you do not need data there.

Comment: @Gortonington if I remove the headers I get:
result {"StatusCode":200,"Response":["�\b��������r��OJ34225J�00231I37�064N5I�0LN1K56�˴�%���"]}

Expected it is a string like this 0032T000028dgyRZZZ (working with ampscript)

If i put back the headers I get
Sorry, something went wrong: "Unable to retrieve security descriptor for this frame."

Comment: Tried 

  `var contentType = "text/html";`
    `var payload = "Accept-Encoding";`
    `var url = "https://xxxxxx/sk_generator?email=test@test.com";`
    `var headerValues = ["gzip", "deflate", "sdch", "br"];`
     `var responseContent = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerValues);` getting 
Sorry, something went wrong: "A pair of repeating parameter value lists were passed to an AMP HTTPPost function but the lists to not match.  Parameter list pairs must have a matching number of items in each list.\r\n  Parameter List 1: item count = 4\r\n  Parameter List 2: [null]

Comment: This is because in `headerValues` it is recognizing your list of gzip, deflate, etc. as multiple entries in the array and not as a single one due to the quotes. `headerValues` should be `= ["gzip, deflate, sdch, br"]` like the String you had.

Comment: Thank you sir, it's working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is because despite the **[documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/ssjs_httpPost.html)** saying HTTP.Post only has 4 parameters, it actually has 5. (You can see this inside the example code snippet they share underneath it.)

so you would need to adjust your SSJS to:

```js
    var contentType = "text/html";
    var url = "https://xxxxx/sk_generator?email=test@test.com";
    var payload; //null as no payload is needed
    var headerNames = ["Accept-Encoding"]
    var headerValues = ["gzip, deflate, sdch, br"]
    var responseContent = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues)
    
Write("result " + Stringify(responseContent));
```

This should then replicate the success you were getting with AMPscript.